# Error loading MSP configuration for org Org1MSP

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, membership, bitcoin-testnet

I am facing a problem while creating the channel in HyperLedger Fabric Blockchain

```
ubuntu@Raghav:/mnt/c/fabric-samples/test-network$ ./network.sh createChannel
Creating channel 'mychannel'.
```

If network is not up, starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb

```
Generating channel create transaction 'mychannel.tx'

configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.tx -channelID mychannel
```

The logs are the following ones:

```
2020-10-17 12:16:23.571 IST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2020-10-17 12:16:23.651 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 002 Loaded configuration: /mnt/c/fabric-samples/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml
2020-10-17 12:16:23.651 IST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputChannelCreateTx -> INFO 003 Generating new channel configtx
2020-10-17 12:16:23.668 IST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> FATA 004 Error on outputChannelCreateTx: could not generate default config template: error parsing configuration: could not create application group: failed to create application org: 1 - Error loading MSP configuration for org Org1MSP: could not load a valid ca certificate from directory /mnt/c/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/cacerts: stat /mnt/c/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/cacerts: no such file or directory
+ res=1
Failed to generate channel configuration transaction...
Create channel failed
```

Comment: Hi! Have you generated the crypto material? At your logs, it can be read that there is not a file, which it is a certificate. Could you validate it?

Comment: the question really needs some proper formatting.

Comment: Hi, are you running the test-network in a WSL or WSL2 environment?